# JQuery "get" (via $#ID) is returning an array for a div that only exists once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is really baffling me.

My html has this:

```
<div id="sr">Search results here...</div>
```

and when I do:

```
$('#sr').innerHTML = result;
```

...to set a div to an AJAX result, I get an "undefined" error.

If I do this:

```
$('#sr')[0].innerHTML = result;
```

...i.e. access the first item in the array, then it works!

There is only one element on the page called "sr" so why is it doing this?

Comment: That's because jQuery doesn't have a `innerHTML` method, it's called `html()`.

Comment: jQuery returns a jQuery object, different from the DOM object that was passed.
The jQuery object has properties and methods, different from the DOM object.
You cannot use HTML DOM properties and methods on jQuery objects.

Comment: Ah, that sounds familiar now I hear that. It's been a couple of years since I last used jquery like this so I'd forgotten about this kind of pitfall.  Many thanks.

Comment: `document.getElementById("sr").innerHTML = result;` Much faster access to DOM elements that way. Set up a shorthand function for convenience. `function id(s) { return document.getElementById(s) }` ... `id(sr).innerHTML = result`

Comment: Every day's a schoolday. I always thought that $(#'ID') was synonymous with "document.getElementById('ID')!

Comment: It is with some libraries. jQuery though creates a wrapper object and inserts the found elements into it. That *(and all the processing it needs to do because the `$` function is so heavily overloaded)* increases the overhead a good bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.html()` for getting/setting the html of jquery DOM object:

```
 $('#sr').html(result);
```

or use `get()` or deferring operator(which you already did and works) for converting to javascript DOM object and use its native methods and properties:

```
 $('#sr')[0].innerHTML = result;
```

or

```
 $('#sr').get(0).innerHTML = result;
```

Answer (score 2):

`innerHTML` is a [property of the `Element` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) (part of standard DOM API). Is isn't anything specific to jQuery. But you're trying to reach it from the output of [the jQuery() method](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), which is [a `jQuery` object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery), not an `Element`.

In short, if you decide to use jQuery, [stick to jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString):

```
$('#sr').html(result);
```

If you prefer vanilla JavaScript, stick to it as well:

```
document.getElementById("sr").innerHTML = result;
```